# Spring JPA and Hibernate not auto-creating PostgreSQL db tables

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, heroku-postgres

I'm using Spring JPA and Hibernate to connect to my Heroku PostgreSQL db. Ive written a class Student:

```
@Entity(name = "Student")
@Table(
    name = "Student",
    uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(name = "student_email_unique", columnNames = "email")
    }
)
public class Student {
...
```

And this is my application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<host>:<port>/<dbname>
spring.datasource.username=<user>
spring.datasource.password=<pwd>
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.sql.init.mode=always
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create

javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action=create

spring.jpa.generate.ddl-auto=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

My app connects to the db properly but the table Students is not auto-created. I added the     spring.sql.init.mode=always to the app properties file since this is not an in-memory db. The logs go as:

```
2021-08-19 21:18:05.418  INFO 2224 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication using Java 1.8.0_231 on LAPTOP-08SELGFV with PID 2224 (C:\Users\kalio\eclipse-workspace\demo\target\classes started by kalio in C:\Users\kalio\eclipse-workspace\demo)
2021-08-19 21:18:05.434  INFO 2224 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-08-19 21:18:09.599  INFO 2224 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-08-19 21:18:09.661  INFO 2224 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 28 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-08-19 21:18:14.705  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-08-19 21:18:14.742  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-08-19 21:18:14.743  INFO 2224 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.50]
2021-08-19 21:18:15.083  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-08-19 21:18:15.084  INFO 2224 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 9213 ms
2021-08-19 21:18:16.894  INFO 2224 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-08-19 21:18:20.575  INFO 2224 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-08-19 21:18:20.737  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-08-19 21:18:21.032  INFO 2224 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-08-19 21:18:21.749  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-08-19 21:18:22.376  INFO 2224 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2021-08-19 21:18:38.310  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-08-19 21:18:38.376  INFO 2224 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-08-19 21:18:38.809  WARN 2224 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-08-19 21:18:42.049  INFO 2224 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-08-19 21:18:42.177  INFO 2224 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 39.466 seconds (JVM running for 41.782)
```

Comment: There is a typo, pls use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

Comment: I corrected the typo but the issue persists :/

Comment: `spring.jpa.generate.ddl-auto=true` is wrong, there does not exist such a key. Probably you wanted to write: `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` which is of no use since your very next line is `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`. So try removing the line `spring.jpa.generate.ddl-auto=true` completely from your properties file.

Comment: I removed that also and it didnt auto-create. I was reading something about this auto-create not working for postgresql not in-memory db for safety reasons, in which only certain users can do this task.

Comment: How did you determine the table wasn't there?  I had the same problem, but it was pgadmin3 showing no tables and throwing errors.  Intellij database browser showed that my tables were there (see my "answer" and comment below).  pgadmin3 is completely unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem with Postgresql 13.  I have four tables with ManyToMany relationships between three tables and a OneToMany on the fourth table.  The sequences for all four tables are created, but not tables.

On startup the I get the following in the output:

```
Hibernate: create table account (id  bigserial not null, account_id varchar(255), opened_date date, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table account_person_set (account_id int8 not null, person_set_id int8 not null, primary key (account_id, person_set_id))
Hibernate: create table person (id  bigserial not null, account_id int8, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table person_reservation_set (person_id int8 not null, reservation_set_id int8 not null, primary key (person_id, reservation_set_id))
Hibernate: create table reservable_resource (id  bigserial not null, description varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table reservable_resource_reservation_set (reservable_resource_id int8 not null, reservation_set_id int8 not null, primary key (reservable_resource_id, reservation_set_id))
Hibernate: create table reservation (id  bigserial not null, comments varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table reservation_person_set (reservation_id int8 not null, person_set_id int8 not null, primary key (reservation_id, person_set_id))
Hibernate: create table reservation_resources (reservation_id int8 not null, resources_id int8 not null, primary key (reservation_id, resources_id))
Hibernate: alter table account_person_set add constraint UK_qortuq7nc9ytbjd1najldg362 unique (person_set_id)
Hibernate: alter table account_person_set add constraint FKqvhfkuu4thxedfntcw0kjemlt foreign key (person_set_id) references person
Hibernate: alter table account_person_set add constraint FK47nbhl58befqf3qkvnhd3ybtw foreign key (account_id) references account
Hibernate: alter table person add constraint FKiyv5708nn4k5w34ph5dofk6ag foreign key (account_id) references account
Hibernate: alter table person_reservation_set add constraint FK74dftwa1nmgx7h4cgqsvexcnu foreign key (reservation_set_id) references reservation
Hibernate: alter table person_reservation_set add constraint FKbd4umv4bsu5415jlksxgteyt8 foreign key (person_id) references person
Hibernate: alter table reservable_resource_reservation_set add constraint FK9u01dt439c84km39klflxk2pl foreign key (reservation_set_id) references reservation
Hibernate: alter table reservable_resource_reservation_set add constraint FKr3s6qquluyccbo3qg00gdr8bb foreign key (reservable_resource_id) references reservable_resource
Hibernate: alter table reservation_person_set add constraint FK4vrllnympyak4snbaouipos17 foreign key (person_set_id) references person
Hibernate: alter table reservation_person_set add constraint FKicbdc2an5qhuiwwem0lcc75wp foreign key (reservation_id) references reservation
Hibernate: alter table reservation_resources add constraint FKeee0ergn0dmv0yx91ir13cl0w foreign key (resources_id) references reservable_resource
Hibernate: alter table reservation_resources add constraint FK3ibmdb9y8dq9w9ih59ttfc86 foreign key (reservation_id) references reservation
```

It looks like it is generating the right DDL, but not executing it.

This looks like a bug in Spring.

Comment: This was a bug in pgadmin3.  It showed no tables and threw errors when I tried to view the tables.  I configured the database browser in Intellij the tables were there.  pgadmin3 is so bug ridden it should be deleted.  pgadmin4 is even worse.  It doesn't run at all.

Comment: I had to create the tables manually using the schema.sql in the resource folder. Wasnt able to get the auto generated tables for postgres